# What kind of window is this and how do I handle it with Selenium? Autoit?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a dialog that Windows Detective claims is a "MozillaDialogClass" window, I'm testing in Firefox right now of course.

Here is an image of the window.

[image]

AutoIt IDE doesn't recognize it. Windows Defender can't see any of it's properties so I have no idea what the name of it is or anything else about it. One of the developers says it's a browser specific window. (whatever the heck that is, if it is why can't anything see it?).

Anyone have any ideas on this one? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to use [SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/). Below is an example scenario using SikuliX. Basically, SikuliX automates anything you see on the screen of your desktop computer running Windows, Mac or some Linux/Unix. It uses image recognition powered by OpenCV to identify and control GUI components. This is handy in cases when there is no easy access to a GUI's internals or the source code of the application or web page you want to act on.

Below is a hello world example. This clicks on the spotlight icon on the screen, waits spotlight’s input window appears, and then types “hello world” and hits ENTER.

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;

public class TestSikuli {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Screen s = new Screen();
            try{
                    s.click("imgs/spotlight.png", 0);
                    s.wait("imgs/spotlight-input.png");
                    s.type(null, "hello world\n", 0);
            }
            catch(FindFailed e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

 }
```

You can find sikuli [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-api/1.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

This is a native Dialog from your webbrowser. So it is not easy to handle this with Selenium. What do you want to test in it?

For some reading, see also this question:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver

Comment: I basically just want to click the OK button and dismiss it so it will open the excel document. That appears to be difficult. LOL....

Answer (score 0):

Rather than handling the download window, you could setup Firefox to automatically download the file to a folder:

```java
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in viewer
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\temp");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://www.exinfm.com/free_spreadsheets.html");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Capital Budgeting Analysis")).click();
```

Or to automatically open a file with the default application:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in viewer
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://www.exinfm.com/free_spreadsheets.html");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Capital Budgeting Analysis")).click();
```

Note that you need to update the MIME type (`application/vnd.ms-excel` here) by the one of your file.
The MIME type is the `Content-Type` from the response header.

And if you just want to close the dialog, then I would use AutoIt:

```
WinWait("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]", "", 10)
WinClose("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]")
```